# TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have just created a dictionary in python.

```
stb_info = self.stb_type()
print type(stb_info) #The output gives me dict
```

When I want to run my tread function for each group

```
for group_no, shelves in stb_info:
    self.thread_function(group_no, shelves)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable
```

So, how I can solve this bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `stb_info.items()`. Just iterating over a dict iterates over its keys, so it's trying to unpack a key (a long) into two parts, which isn't possible.

Comment: Or `.iteritems()` since it's Python 2.x.