# Adding contents of a queryset to a list in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, list, loops

I'm pretty new to Django. I'm trying to iterate over my queryset and add the field which happens to be called 'id' of each to a new list.

My end result should be a list looking something like this (for example): [1, 2, 3, 7, 10]

My code looks like this:

```
my_list = []

for foo in bar:
    number = foo.id
    my_list += number
```

I'm getting this error: TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable

The type of foo.id is long

I have tried changing the foo.id to an int or str using:

```
number = str(number)
```

Have also tried the solution here (I'm using Python 2.7): [TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651482/typeerror-long-object-is-not-iterable) but I get this: AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: what is bar ???

Comment: @KHELILIIlyes : it's explained right at the start : "I'm trying to iterate over my queryset"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for why your code raises an error: you'd have to use `my_list.append(number)` (`my_list += anything` is a shortcut for `my_list.extends(anything)` which expects an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) and will append all values from this iterable to `my_list`).

Now actually, the pythonic way here would be to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead, ie :

```
my_list = [foo.id for foo in bar]
```

**But** since it's about a Django queryset, the right solution is to use [`QuerySet.values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
bar = MyModel.objects.values_list("id", flat=True)
```

which will result in `bar` being an iterable over your queryset's 'id' values. And if you *really* need a list, then you just have to pass `bar` to the `list` constructor:

```
my_list = list(bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to iterate over queryset to get id of each object. I suggest to use values_list() like. which will give you list of id of each object in queryset.

```
ids = bar.values_list('id', flat=True)
```